# No output when adding data to the database

Tags: javascript, express, axios, vuejs3

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useExamStore } from '../../stores/examStore';
import axios from 'axios';

const store = useExamStore();
const exams = store.exams;
let newQuestion = {
  questionText: ref(""),
  questionType: ref(""),
  option: ref([]),
  answerIndex: ref(0)
};

let selectedExam = exams[0].examName;

const addQuestion = async () => {
  try {
    store.loading = true
    const examToUpdate = exams.find((exam) => exam.examName === selectedExam);

    const { questionText, questionType, options, cevapI } = newQuestion;



    if (!examToUpdate) {
      throw new Error('Exam not found');
    }


    const id = examToUpdate._id;
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      `http://localhost:3000/exams/${id}/questions`,
      {
        questionText: questionText.value,
        questionType: questionType.value,
        options: options.value,
        answerIndex: answerIndex.value,
      }
    );

    console.log("Question added to the database:", data);

    
    newQuestion.questionText.value = "";
    newQuestion.questionType.value = "";

    await store.getExams();
  
  } catch (error) {
    store.loading = false
    store.error = true;
    store.errorMesssage = error.message;
  }

};

</script>
```

And this is the Express.js server code

```
router.post("/:id/questions", async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const { questionText, questionType, options, answerIndex } = req.body;
  try {
    const updatedExam = await Exam.findByIdAndUpdate(
      id,
      {
        $push: {
          questions: {
            questionText: questionText,
            options: options,
            questionType: questionType,
            answerIndex: answerIndex,
          },
        },
      },
      { new: true }
    );
    if (!updatedExam) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "Exam not found" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error" });
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

After the axios request, i checked the database and the newQuestion is added succesfully to the database. But i cant see the "Question added to database" log. Page is stuck in loading state. I tried to remove loading event and it didnt work. Because of that problem, i cant reset the reactive form data (newQuestion)

Comment: It is likely that your API endpoint (`http://localhost:3000/exams/{id}/questions`) is not properly terminating the response and so the client is left waiting even though no more work is left to be done.  Please add your API endpoint's ExpressJS code to your post.

Comment: @GregFenton i added backend code to the post. Please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning a response status in the event of a successful operation.

In your `router.post()` change:

```js
if (!updatedExam) {
  return res.status(404).json({ error: "Exam not found" });
}
```

to

```js
if (!updatedExam) {
  return res.status(404).json({ error: "Exam not found" });
} else {
  return res.status(200).json({ message: "success!  well done!!!"});
}
```

Your client code seems to be waiting to get a `data` field as a response value, so you might want to include that in the successful (and even in the error) responses.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was translating this project code to my native language for school project. I was annoyed and tried everything except checking backend code lol